# Angular & iOS: performance with 1 MB json file

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Just a quick question.

I'm designing a small app with some data.
These data are in a Json file: 1500 records, 1 MB of size.

Is better to use a db (SQLite plugin for Cordova) or the Json is not so big?
I'm worried about performance...

The app is a quiz app: I have to query for 30 random questions one time!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use SQLite because maybe in the future you want to increase records and with SQlite you have a better control.